# phpmailer SMTP client information

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am updating some contact forms on several websites i made, and i am using phpmailer for it.

I'm using the SMTP method where you fill in the username and password of the email client where it needs to send to, like below:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'info@company.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypass';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('info@company.com', $email);
$mail->addAddress('info@company.com');              
$mail->addReplyTo(''.$email.'');
```

My problem is i have to get my client his/hers emailaddress with their password, how could i solve this without asking my clients for their email information.

Comment: Read the info from a data file.  Have a password-protected page on the site where your customer can fill out a form to update the info (a write-only form is safest, where you never show the data).  Of course as long as you have FTP access to the site you can read the file so it's more to make updating easier than to keep the information from you.

Comment: Thanks alot Dave S! Didn't even think about that, i will try it!